# Missing file extension "tsx" for "./reducer" error after using eslint-config-airbnb

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

I am using eslint and prettier code formatters for my project. After using airbnb I am getting errors like

- Missing file extension "tsx" for "./reducer"
- Missing file extension "tsx" for "./saga"

reducer has index.tsx and so does saga folder.
I have tried import/extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx"] in my .eslintrc.yml file but still getting the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`eslint-config-airbnb` has this rule enabled:

```
    'import/extensions': ['error', 'ignorePackages', {
      js: 'never',
      mjs: 'never',
      jsx: 'never',
    }],
```

See [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/imports.js#L139).

If want to turn it off, you could override it in your own eslint config file like so:

```
'import/extensions': 'off'
```

More information on how you could configure this specific rule can be found [here](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/extensions.md)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried setitng 'import/extensions' off and tsx to off too but still the error persists
Here is my .eslintrc.yml file content
parserOptions:
  ecmaFeatures:
    jsx: true
  ecmaVersion: 2018
  sourceType: module
parser: babel-eslint
plugins:
  - react
  - prettier
settings:
  import/parsers:
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
  react:
    version: detect
  import/extensions: ["error", "always", { "tsx": "never", "ts": "never" }]
  import/resolver:
    node:
      paths: ["src"]
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx"]
rules:
  {...}

Comment: Could you add that to your original question with the formatting applied?

Anyway, the `import/extensions: off` should be put under `rules`.

Comment: Thank you so much Jackyef. At most of the places import/extensions are under settings and not rules. I was also doing the same mistake. You saved my day. 
Thanks